# Google script not retrieving value of HTML textarea prompt

Tags: html, google-apps-script, textarea

I have a HTML prompt for a spreadsheet with 2 input spaces, one for "usuario" which it a text input and the other one for "mensaje" which is textarea.
My script needs to retrieve both values, intert "mensaje" in a specific cell, and download a PDF with "usuario" in the name.

Everything works perfect when it has 2 input type="text", but i need the second one to allow multiple rows so I had to change it.

Now it seems like the textarea "mensaje" information is not transmiting correctly to the script, it isn't inserted into the cell. Everything else works normally.

It doesn't show any error, it just doesn't retrieve the values, so it doesn't insert it, so the downloaded PDF is blank.

I'm not sure what I would need to change to make textarea work correctly, I don't have a lot of experience programing, mostly mashing together parts I found online to make it do what I want.

IndexTexto.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <form id="textform" style="font-size:16px">
    Usuario:<br>
    <input type="text" name="usuario" style="width: 300px;">
    <br>
    <br>
    Mensaje:<br>
    <textarea id="mensaje" rows="14" cols="95"></textarea>
    <br><br><br>
     <input type="button" value="Descargar" class="action " style="font-size:16px" style="height: 150px;" style="text-align:center;" 
        onclick="google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
            .descargarTexto(this.parentNode)" />
  </form>
</html>
```

Relevant parts of DescargarTexto.gs

```
function promptTexto() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('IndexTexto').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setHeight(400).setWidth(700);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Ingresar texto');
}


function descargarTexto(form) {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('5').setHeight(10).setWidth(100), "Creando");
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Link de pago');
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var usuario = form.usuario
  var mensaje = form.mensaje
  sheet.getRange(15,3).setValue(mensaje)

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var range = sheet.getRange(15,3)
  var values = range.getValues()
  
  Logger.log(mensaje)
  Logger.log(values)
  
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "dd-MM-yy")
  var filename = usuario + "_" + date + ".pdf"; // Please set the filename here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access undefined object in `form.mensaje`. If you try to print the `form` in your `descargarTexto(form)` function. It will print something like this: `{=DEF, usuario=ABC}`. The key name for mensaje is not defined. This can be fixed by adding name="mensaje" attribute to mensaje text area.

**Note:** *You can view logs at **Executions** tab of your App Script project*

Your code should look like this:

```
<textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" rows="14" cols="95"></textarea>
```

**Example:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]